# Twitter Bootstrap popover doesn't showup

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am posting this question because, in my search, I didn't find anything that is similar to my situation. I tried many things looking at all other solutions but nothing work. Here is my situation:

I have a textarea which I create dynamically using handlebars.js template:

```
{{#datacontext}}
<textarea rows="10" cols="41" id="selector" rel="popover" 
          data-content="{{data_value}}" data-html="true" 
          style="color:Black;background:none;" class="uneditable-textarea"   
          readonly="true" >{{data_value}}</textarea>
{{/datacontext}}
```

Then in jQuery I have all these below codes but nothing works. I am pretty sure I have popover in my bootstrap.js script:

```
     $('body').popover({
            selector: '[rel=popover]',
            placement: 'left'
        });

 $('#selector').popover({ trigger: 'hover'
                            , placement: 'left'
                            , html: true
                            , content: function () {
                                return $("#poContent").html();
                            }
    });

    $("[rel=popover]").popover({ placement: 'left' });

    $('[rel=popover]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('#poContent').html();
        }
    });
```

I tried putting the content in `#poConten` t as well.

I would appreciate your help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your js templater works after document ready and after your script run. **For debug** try run it after document ready and some delay (using `setTimeot()`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function(){
$('body').popover({
            selector: '[rel=popover]',
            placement: 'left'
        });

 $('#selector').popover({ trigger: 'hover'
                            , placement: 'left'
                            , html: true
                            , content: function () {
                                return $("#poContent").html();
                            }
    });

    $("[rel=popover]").popover({ placement: 'left' });

    $('[rel=popover]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('#poContent').html();
        }
    });
 }, 2000); // 2 sec delay 

}) ;
```

Comment: yes, you are right this works. However I found another another solution just after posting my question, which works:   $("#selector").live("hover", function () {
            $(this).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    return $('#poContent').html();
                },
                placement: 'left',
                container: '#selector',
                title: 'Some Title'
            });
        });

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue. I have accepted your answer.